# Sidekiq queue for specify object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, worker

I use this worker for process

```
class CreateOrUpdateContactWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options retry: 2, queue: 'contact_updater', concurrency: 1

    sidekiq_retries_exhausted do |msg|
        Airbrake.notify(error_message: "Contact update failed", session: { msg: msg })
    end

    def perform(user_id, changed_fields, update_address = false)
        ContactUpdater.create_or_update_contact(user_id, changed_fields, update_address: update_address)
    end
end
```

In the user model I have `after_commit` callback

```
def update_mautic_contact
    CreateOrUpdateContactWorker.perform_async(id, previous_changes.keys, ship_address_changed || false)
end
```

The problem is when user updated twice at the same time, because to `create_or_update_contact` need some time. How can I limit threads only for specify user? That each task will be executed one by one for specify user_id.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have `redis` as part of your infrastructure but what you are describing is a race condition. To solve it you need mutex/locks to your critical path `create_or_update_contact`.

The race condition here is happening between two async workers/processes so you can't just use simple ruby mutex/lock. You need a distributed mutex that uses a central lock storage/keeper. This: https://github.com/kenn/redis-mutex should do it for you but you will need `redis` database.

Basically your code will something like:

```
class CreateOrUpdateContactWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options retry: 2, queue: 'contact_updater', concurrency: 1

    sidekiq_retries_exhausted do |msg|
        Airbrake.notify(error_message: "Contact update failed", session: { msg: msg })
    end

    def perform(user_id, changed_fields, update_address = false)
        RedisMutex.with_lock("#{user_id}_create_or_update_contact") do
            ContactUpdater.create_or_update_contact(user_id, changed_fields, update_address: update_address)
        end
    end
end
```

So if you have 2 user updates for user_id=1 at the same time the first to acquire the lock/mutex called `1_create_or_update_contact` will execute first and will block the other call till it finishes and then the second call will start.

This will fix your problem :) I think `redis` is needed, useful and handful. I hardly can think of any of my rails projects without having to use `redis`.

Answer (score 0):

I realised it with Redis, but without any gems. I used condition before execute worker:

```
def update_mautic_contact
    if Rails.current.get("CreateOrUpdateContactWorkerIsRunning_#{id}")
        Redis.current.set("CreateOrUpdateContactWorkerIsRunning_#{id}", true)
        CreateOrUpdateContactWorker.perform_in(1.minutes, id, changed_fields)
    else
        Redis.current.set("CreateOrUpdateContactWorkerIsRunning_#{id}", true)
        CreateOrUpdateContactWorker.perform_async(id, changed_fields)
    end
end
```

and inside worker:

```
class CreateOrUpdateContactWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options retry: 2, queue: 'contact_updater', concurrency: 1

    sidekiq_retries_exhausted do |msg|
        Airbrake.notify(error_message: "Contact update failed", session: { msg: msg })
    end

    def perform(user_id, changed_fields, update_address = false)
        ContactUpdater.create_or_update_contact(user_id, changed_fields, update_address: update_address)
        Redis.current.del("CreateOrUpdateContactWorkerIsRunning_#{user_id}")
    end
end
```